# Forfiles, move files that were created in [*Month]

Tags: windows, date, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a problem with `forfiles` syntax. I want to write a simple `forfiles` command, that will:

1. Select files, that were modified in January,February,March, etc.
2. Move these files to another folder.

but I'm having problems to write proper syntax. Here is what I wrote at this point.

```
forfiles /m *.file /d (What do I write here?) /C "cmd /c move @file C:\Users\User1\Desktop\New folder"
```

Date modified format is: `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Comment: Not a solution to the problem, but enclose `move` target path in escaped quotes: `forfiles /m *.file /d (What do I write here?) /C "cmd /c move @file \"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\New folder\""` (or write `0x22` instead of `\"`)...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you want is possible with `forfiles` unless you can process the list of months in reverse order (first move files with `/d +07/08/2016`, then with `/d +01/07/2016`, then `/d +01/06/2016`, and so on).

If PowerShell is an option you may have better luck using that, e.g. like this:

```
Get-ChildItem *.file |
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Month -eq 8 } |
  Move-Item -Destination 'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\New folder'
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering. PowerShell is an option, I gues. Unfortunately this is 4th day I am creating Batch scripts, so It's hard to understand, what exactly is written in code, you added to your message.

In my program, i have simple menu, that runs several lines of commands when option is chosen.
All of them are simple : Cd, if not exist - mkdir, and i am not quite sure, if I can use this code in my script, or do I need to add something to my code?  Also, could you please explain, how does month switching works? Do i need to change -eq 8 to month order number?

Answer (score 0):

To filter out all files modified in a certain month (June 2016 in the following example), you could use two nested `forfiles` loops, where the outer one passes all files modified on or after the first day of the month to the inner one, which returns all items out of them that are modified on or before the last day of the month:

```
> nul 2>&1 forfiles /D +01/06/2016 /C "forfiles forfiles /M @file /D -30/06/2016 /C 0x22cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE > con echo @fdate0x09@ftime0x09@path0x22"
```

This script returns a list of matching files with their modification dates and times. To move the files to another directory (for instance, `C:\Backup\June-2016`), the command line looks like this:

```
> nul 2>&1 forfiles /D +01/06/2016 /C "forfiles forfiles /M @file /D -30/06/2016 /C 0x22cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE move 00x7822@path00x7822 00x7822C:\Backup\June2016\\@file00x78220x22"
```

The redirections avoid empty lines and error messages to be output by `forfiles`.